# Java String Format array

Tags: java, arrays, string, format

i am trying to format a string as follows

```
System.out.println("unique number is :"+ number[b]);
System.out.println("unique number formatted to 28  is :"+ String.format("%-28s",number[b]).replace(' ','0'))
```

there is no issue when "number" is a string that is shorter than 28, it adds the 0's to the left, but when the string is longer than 28 it dosnt shorten it, am i doing anything wrong ?

its an extract from a loop BTW

Many thanks

Comment: how do you want it shortend? Shortening numbers by cutting of digits normally doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formatter doesn't cut your `String`, it only makes sure it uses at least 28 spaces.

You would have to do something like:

```
if (str.length() > 28) {
    str = str.subString(0, 28);
}
```

or maybe

```
if (str.length() > 28) {
    str = str.subString(str.length() - 28, str.length());
}
```

to limit the size.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that `format` is not working as you expect is clear from the javadoc for the [`java.util.Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) class.  It says:

> "The optional *width* is a non-negative decimal integer indicating the **minimum number** of characters to be written to the output."